# Ruled surface-Saddle surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Good evening to everybody.
Since the last 4 weeks I am reading the Differential Geometry book of Barrett O Neill and I have some questions concerning the definition of a ruled surface on page 145. Specifically he says the following: '' A ruled surface is a surface swept out by a straight line L
moving along a curve b. The various positions of the generating line L
are called the rulings of the surface. Such a surface always has a ruled
parametrization
$ x(u,v)=b(u)+v \delta(u) $  . We call b the base curve and d the director curve, although d is usually pictured
as a vector field on b pointing along the line L. ''

I do not understand why , since the straight line moves along the curve b , does he write $ \delta(u) $ and not just a constant vector $ q $ for example. Isnt a straight line always parallel to a vector when it moves along the basis curve ?
Related to this is the exercise 6 in the same chapter where he asks to find two ruled parametrizations with different rulings of the saddle surface defined as $ z= x   y $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where O'Neill writes "moving along" it means *in an arbitrary way*, not necessarily by parallel translation.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your clarification. Then it makes sense. Ok, and concerning the ruled parametrization of the saddle surface $ z=xy $ do you have maybe any idea on how to start?

Comment: Can you see any way to locate lines on that surface? :)

Comment: No, I cannot see any way. I cannot even see which is the basis curve. I could guess it could be some hyperbola ( since at constant Z we indeed have hyperbolas which have smaller and smaller eccentricities as Z increases ) but I cannot see how a relation of the form $b(u)+v d(u)$  can give a point of the surface.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the parametrisation. I changed my perspective, instead of taking Z-sections, I took Y-sections. So if y=C
 is fixed, then we have straight lines z=xC
 so moving along the Y-axis (this is the ruling curve !) we get a point of the form $(0,t,0)+sd(t)$
 , where the vector d(t)
 lies on the line z=xC
 and has only z and x nonzero components , so we write $d(t)=(x(t),0,z(t))$
. Assuming that d(t)
 has unit norm, and since $z(t)/x(t)=t$
 , we get that $d(t)=(1/( \sqrt{1+t^2}),0,t/(\sqrt{1+t^2}))$
. Thus $x(s,t)=(0,t,0)+s (1/( \sqrt{1+t^2}),0,t/(\sqrt{1+t^2}))$